# Error installing RQDA

Tags: macos, installation, r, rstudio

I'm having some trouble installing RQDA on MacOS 10.14.5 Mojave, Rstudio (from Anaconda)running R 3.5.1. I installed Xquartz 2.7.11 and GTK+ 2.24.17, but when I try to install the RQDA package I get these error messages:

```
* installing *source* package ‘cairoDevice’ ...

** package ‘cairoDevice’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

checking for pkg-config... no

ERROR: Cannot find pkg-config.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘cairoDevice’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/cairoDevice’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘cairoDevice’ had non-zero exit status

* installing *source* package ‘Matrix’ ...

** package ‘Matrix’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

** libs

x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
-I"/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -DNTIMER -I./SuiteSparse_config -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/include -fPIC -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -c CHMfactor.c -o CHMfactor.o

/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang: command not found

make: *** [CHMfactor.o] Error 127

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Matrix’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Matrix’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘Matrix’ had non-zero exit status

* installing *source* package ‘RSQLite’ ...

** package ‘RSQLite’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

** libs

x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++
-I"/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -DRSQLITE_USE_BUNDLED_SQLITE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX -I"/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/BH/include" -I"/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/plogr/include" -I"/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -I/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/include -fPIC -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda/- -fdebug-prefix-map==/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -c DbColumn.cpp -o DbColumn.o

/bin/sh: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++: command not found

make: *** [DbColumn.o] Error 127

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RSQLite’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/RSQLite’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RSQLite’ had non-zero exit status

* installing *source* package ‘RGtk2’ ...

** package ‘RGtk2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

checking for pkg-config... no

checking for INTROSPECTION... no

checking for GTK... no

configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/RGtk2’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RGtk2’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘RGtk2’, ‘cairoDevice’ are not available for package ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/gWidgetsRGtk2’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘Matrix’ is not available for package ‘igraph’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/igraph’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘igraph’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘RSQLite’, ‘gWidgetsRGtk2’, ‘RGtk2’, ‘igraph’ are not available for package ‘RQDA’

* removing ‘/Users/danielanzola/anaconda3/lib/R/library/RQDA’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘RQDA’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Install R patch for windows.Work like a charm.

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rtest.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.